# Dynamically importing css files into react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, use-state

i am wondering is there a way to dynamically import a css file into react.
say i have a css file named style-light.css and i have another named style-dark.css.
is there a way to use react state or some other method to dynamically import the css files into the component based on the current value of the state ?
eg

```
import "../style-light.css" // default import


export default function TestImport(){
const [switch, setSwitch] = useState("light");

if(switch === "dark"){
import "../style-dark.css" // adds the style-dark import below the light one to overwrite the light css.
}

return (
<div>
<button onClick={()=> setSwitch("dark")}> click to get dark css </button>
</div>
)
}
```

bascially something like that?
any insight will be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

For that I would recommend that you use CSS variables and only one CSS file. You can change the values of your variables based on a class applied on your page body. For example:

**variables.css**

```
:root {
    --textColor: black;
}

[class="dark-theme"] {
    --textColor: white;
}
```

With javascript you can add or remove the class from your html document, like this

**component.js**

```js
document.documentElement.classList.add('dark-theme')
document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark-theme')
```

On your components styles you can use the variables with `var(--variable)`

**component.css**

```
.my-component-class {
  color: var(--textColor);
}
```

### Option 2

Use some CSS-IN-JS library like styled-components or emotion, you can use a ThemeProvider to change our theme accordingly with some state in your application. See this example here: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming